# EJB as Web Service - Session Timeout

Tags: web-services, jboss, session-timeout

I would like to know how to increase the session-timeout of an EJB-based Web Service.

Can the automatically created web.xml found in the JBOSS_HOME/server/default/tmp/deploy/WebService.war/WEB-INF be modified or customize the creation of this file?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss Application Server has a default session bean timeout of 30 minutes, which is configured in server/default/conf/standardjboss.xml.change the max-bean-life.

```
<max-bean-life>1800</max-bean-life>
```